# How to remove a bad date

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I have a table that is imported from an Excel spreadsheet into a staging table. There is a column labeled [EndDate] that is the termination date for an employee.

I recently noticed that I have a bad date that has started to show up for employees that have been rehired.

the EndDate goes to '9999-12-31'. I simply need a script that will remove this date as I process the new information every month.

I currently have a scheduled job that runs on the first of the month so I figured the easiest way to do this would be to use an "Execute SQL Task" at the end of the Data Flow and remove the bad date. I tried this already with the following script.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[HRIS_EEMaster]
SET [EndDate] = NULL
WHERE EndDate = '9999-12-31'
```

But it didn't work. I may have the placement wrong.

My SSIS flow is as such.
ExecutleSQLTask (Truncate the Staging Table) -> DataFlowTask (Load the Staging Table) -> ExecutleSQLTask (Replace missing CostCenters in the Staging Table)

Then I thought I could add another ExecutleSQLTask (Remove the Bad Date) using the above script.

Hopefully someone has a better idea.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: That approach should work.  It looks like your query is updating a master table (`HRIS_EEMaster`) -- when does staging get pushed to master?

Comment: And "didn't work" means what exactly?  The data did not get updated?  The job did not run?  Are there any errors?

Comment: maybe your date literal doesn't follow the conevntions set by your locale. a quick and dirty workaround might be restricting by date constituents: `WHERE year(date) = 9999 AND MONTH(date) = 12 AND DAY(date) = 31`.

Comment: If the problem is in the query and not in the task, you can try to use `WHERE date between '9999-12-31 00:00' and '9999-12-31 23:59'`.

Comment: Is [EndDate] nullable? That's the most common reason for using "the end of time" as a value for an ending date.

Comment: @mr.Reband, I am updating the master data. and since you pointed that out, i see what I have done wrong and why it did not work. I have put the task in the wrong job. I either need to remove the date from the staging table or move the task to the job that populated the master data. (cant believe I missed that!) Thank you.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry for the vagueness, It did not remove the date like it should, but I just realized that it was an error on my part (see previous comment).

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall', the [EndDate] is nullable. If the Employee is still employed, then the filed id NULL. These employees are rehired from a previous term and the system has a glitch that puts the end of time as their term date. My company is looking into why it is doing this but it loks like the fix is a ways out.